# Visual Studio 2010 DevServer gives me 403 error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, windows-7, asp.net-development-serv

I have a C# MVC project created in Visual Studio 2010 Professional (VS) on Windows 7 but I am not able to run it and debug it in VS.

VS gives me: Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server
The development server starts tho on http://localhost:63785/ but that gives me Server Error in '/' Application. HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden. Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

I am able to start the application directly using: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.EXE" /port:8080 /path:"D:\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\ but I am not able to use VS debugging that way
My colleague tried to run the application using IIS but that gives him the 403 error as well.

I dont have much experience regarding IIS or ASP, I tried to google it and tried few ideas but none seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once in firefox when the following checkbox was activated:

(Website right click in solution explorer)->

Property Pages->

Start Options->

Server / NTLM Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you accidentally restricted access to all pages of your project? Check `authentication` / `authorization` sections in web.config

Comment: i havent manipulated with that, there is only something generated by the visual studio. But it must be something i did cause when i create a new clean project it works.